# ReactJS & Laravel Menu Links Showing component in header only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on Laravel & ReactJS application, while i am linking the pages using reactjs, the components are loading in header only. But i want to show inside main div of bootstrap.

Code i am using:

```
            <Router>
        <div className="page-header page-header--style2 header-sticky">
        <div className="page-header-top">
        <div className="container">
        <div className="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="public/theme/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div className="page-header-menu">
        <div className="container">
        <ul className="menu">


        <li><Link to="/proclean/test">About Us2</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/proclean/services">Services</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/proclean/calculator">Cleaning Calculator</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/proclean/booking">Service Booking</Link></li>


        <Route exact  path='/proclean/test' component={Test}></Route>
        <Route exact  path='/proclean/services' component={Services}></Route>
        <Route exact  path='/proclean/calculator' component={Calc.Calc}></Route>
        <Route exact  path='/proclean/booking' component={Booking.Booking}></Route>


        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        </Router>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hj2E.png)

And my main index.js is

```
                import React, { Component } from 'react';
            import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
            import Header from './Header';
            import Home from './HomePage/Home';
            import Footer from './Footer';
            export default class Index extends Component {
                render() {
                    return (

                        <div>
                            <Header />
                            <Home />
                            <Footer />
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }

            if (document.getElementById('app')) {
                ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('app'));
            }
```

SO i just want to load every content in my div container instead header.

Regards,
Ritu

Comment: show as your header if possible

Comment: Show your full code please. Where does the first code block come from ?